# How can I see https header infos sent by a reverse proxy to target server?

Tags: https, proxy, tomcat7

I have a tomcat server with an application and an apache2 2-way-ssl reverse proxy server. I want to send an https request throught this reverse proxy server to the target server. I want to see the header of the request sent by the proxy to the target server. How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dumpio Apache module to log the proxied headers.

See https://viewsby.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/configuring-mod_dumpio-with-apache2-in-ubuntu/ for how to enable the module and point to the desired log file.